# How to filter out all the dates that are older than 3 months , referencing the current date

Tags: excel, vba

i want to filter the dates that are older than 3 months and i want to have the system variable

```
Dim Date3M_ago As Date
Date3M_ago = Worksheets("Engine").Range("C1")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=46, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria1:= Date3M_ago
```

'`Worksheets("Engine").Range("C1")` is the cell where i have the formula that shows me the date 3 months ago , referencing the current date

The problem is i can't write `criteria1:= < Date3M_ago` , because it gives me error. the correct syntax would be `criteria1:= "< 8/28/2019"` but that's a fixed date and i don't need that.

Comment: You autofilter on column 46, but you only try to autofilter columns A:C. By definition an autofilter cannot be applied while excluding the column the autofilter is applied on. Either include (up to) column AS in your range, or set the field you want to filter as one within your range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully something in here is usefull for you:

You say you need to filter out dates older than today minus three months (as that is what your formula in `Worksheets("Engine").Range("C1")` does. The same can be done through VBA with `Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Date, -3)`,or even `DateAdd` as per @Plutian his answer. If this is not what your intention was, you can instead reference your own variable again in it's place but make sure to turn it into a double value to use within the filter > `CDbl(Date3M_ago)`.

- Why do we turn this into a double? Depending on your Windows Regional Settings, the use of dates as criteria can give you unexpected results. [This is because Excel sees the dates as a US date](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm). One way around this, as per the link, is to use Long variables, however using Double variables will work with decimals and therefor it's saver to use `CDbl` in my option to account for date-time values.

If we put the above into practice with some sample data like below (dates are formatted "d-m-yyyy":

[image]

A piece of code to filter on column C would look like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Date3M_ago As Date
Date3M_ago = Worksheets("Engine").Range("F1")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    'All options below will work, remove the lines you don't want to use:
    .Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Date, -3)
    .Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(DateAdd("m", -3, Date))
    .Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(Worksheets("Engine").Range("F1"))
    .Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(Date3M_ago)
End With

End Sub
```

Notice how the field to be filtered is in the range to be filtered, e.g.: the third column? The output would look like:

[image]

Comment: One more question kind sir , before i close this.How do i make the field area variable ?Like to search for a name every time

Comment: @hunter, you could apply a variable instead of the `Field:=3`. It would for example become something like `Field:= X`. Now you can assign any number of column withing the `.Range("A:C")`, so meaning 1, 2 or 3 to the X variable. If you need to increase the range, you can do so and assign other columns.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
Dim Date3M_ago As Date

Date3M_ago = Worksheets("Engine").Range("C1")

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=46, Criteria1:="<" & Date3M_ago, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Depending on your settings, this might give you unexpected results (as it did on my end).

Answer (score 1):

Autofilter cannot be applied to a column outside of the range you are trying to autofilter. In your example you are trying to filter column AT (`Field:=46`) but only apply the range from column A to C. Either apply column AT to your autofilter like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AT").AutoFilter Field:=46, Operator:= _
```

Or change your field to be one included in the range:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:= _
```

Also a suggestion, replace the reference to cell filled with your date 30 days ago with a vba calculation instead to prevent breaking:

```
Date3M_ago = DateAdd("m", -3, Now)
```

Comment: Interestingly, while `DateAdd` returns a date value, it will not always work as a variable in the criteria (depemding on Windows Regional Settings I guess). To make it work, you can wrap it into a `CDbl` > `Criteria1:=">" & CDbl(DateAdd("M", -3, Date))`. Futhermore +1 for the nice idea of using `DateAdd` :)

Comment: Thanks JvdV, that is indeed interesting to know. I might have use of this for a project that is coming up though as I'll be using autofilter quite a bit.

Comment: Also would CDate work as a substitute of CDbl in this case?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. It would even mean overkill as `DateAdd` returns a date on it's own. Check the link I provided in my answer, for better understanding of why the filtering wouldn't work with date variables.

Comment: Fair enough. As I said, just trying to learn as I might have use for it later. Thanks!

Comment: It's something I also find difficult to understand as to why MS have made this so difficult :S

Comment: I suppose it's to do with compatibility with different date format customs. It is near impossible to predict and account for every different custom. I helped someone not too long ago as he used the German custom of writing dates without years as ```dd.mm.``` which (of course) completely threw his code.